# Reading and Using CSV Files

Tags: python, csv

I have the following quiz program

```
def trivia():
score=0
myFile = open("farming.csv","r") # opens the CSV file and stores it in the array myFile
lines = myFile.readlines() # reads the lines of the CSV file into the variable players
questionnum=1
while questionnum < 6:

    for p in lines:
        data = p.split(",") #splits each cell of the CSV file into its parts
    questions = data[0]
    answera = data[1]
    answerb = data[2]
    answerc = data[3]
    CorrectAnswer = data[4]
    print("Question #",questionnum)
    print(questions) #prints the question and the 3 answers
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(answera)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(answerb)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(answerc)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    answer = input("Answer? ") #asks the user for their answer
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".")

    if answer == CorrectAnswer: #checks if the answer is correct and prints approptiate responses
        print("That is the correct answer")
        score=score+1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("That is not the correct answer")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Your current score is", score)
    print("")

    questionnum = questionnum+1

myFile.close()
```

Problem is, when it loops around, it only ever uses the first question in the csv file and never progresses to the next. How can I make it do that?
AND
If I wanted to randomise the questions, how could I do that? I have tried playing with `random.choice` but I cant seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance....
CS

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the line for splitting on ","

```
for p in lines:
    data = p.split(",") #splits each cell of the CSV file into its parts
```

When you do this, it will keep replacing the `data` variable in-place with each line.  So when this for loop ends, data will always only contain the last question in your file as a single list. Try something like this instead:

```
data = [p.strip().split(",") for p in lines]
```

You'll want to do this **before** entering your while loop though so you don't run this over and over.

Then `data` will be an array of lines split on the commas (each one is a list) and you can index into it like so:

```
questions = data[questionnum-1][0]
answera = data[questionnum-1][1]
answerb = data[questionnum-1][2]
answerc = data[questionnum-1][3]
```

To get randomizing working, easiest way is probably just shuffle your lines before going into your while loop, e.g.

```
import random
random.shuffle(lines)
```

Also FWIW, there is a python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library that handles the delimiter splitting for you and is a bit more robust.

Comment: I am getting this error:
data = [p.split(",") for p in lines.strip()] #splits each cell of the CSV file into its parts
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry typo on my part. The strip() is a string method that gets rid of extra leading/trailing whitespace/newline characters from your lines.  Should read:  `[p.strip().split(",") for p in lines]`. Fixed.